# Laravel not working in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5.1

I have tried to install laravel 5.1 in ubuntu 15.04 after following steps in this page http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu

but after running laravel.example.com, browser gives  "Loading page error" 
I tried to run`php artisan serv` then run http://localhost:8000 in browser
 but same result .

Comment: Did you check apache error logs?

Comment: have you check permissions of project folder as well as permission of vendor and storage folder.??

Comment: Yeas, when I running this url http://localhost/laravel/public this error come `child pid 8856 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)` in error log file but http://localhost:8000 didn't print any errors in log file

Comment: in beginning i give permissions 777 for storage folder, after that I give permissions   777 for all project files

Answer (score 0):

My laravel app run on vagrant box, System is ubuntu 15.0.4

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead

You can install homestead, so easy and convenient

Answer (score 0):

It Solved by running this command in project folder `php -S localhost:8787` -t public .

> you can change port to any port you want